# ANDROID Swipe-able Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-fragmentactivity

I've swipe-able tabs in one activity. When a user clicks on an EditText field to enter , I launch another activity to take the input and then I revert back to the tab activity. However, whenever I return to this activity with tabs, only the 1st tab is shown.

How do I display a different tab when I revert back to this activity after taking input from a different activity? Ideally, I'd want to return to the tab/fragment from which the intent was passed.

EDIT : FIXED

This piece of code helped me solve this issue.

```
int pos = bundle.getInt("pos");
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(pos);
tab.select();
```

Comment: use onActivityResult when you call Second activity to type

Comment: check out the answer

Comment: please post your code for the two activities and how you manage your fragments

Comment: yep, add your both activities.

Comment: I fixed this issue using this piece of code.                                                  int pos = bundle.getInt("pos");
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(pos);
            tab.select();

Comment: Resolved the issue using TabLayout's select method. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code helped me resolve the issue.

```
 int pos = bundle.getInt("pos");
 TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(pos);
 tab.select();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Activity when user clicks the edittext should Lauch another activity.

```
 case R.id.btn_edit_text_clicked:
 Intent i = new Intent(this,  SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In onActivityResult()

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
```

After user types the text in edit text of SecondActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("ANY_VARIABLE_NAME", [YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_VALUE]);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```